# Possible to block a URL (vs. IP address) using Windows Firewall?

Tags: windows-7, security, firewall, url, windows-firewall

Blocking an IP address with the Windows Firewall integrated into Windows 7 is reasonably straightforward.

But is there any way to block a URL (which can resolve to different IP addresses at different times) using Windows Firewall in Windows 7?

Comment: Nope, perhaps just stick it in your hosts file pointing to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, that's exactly what I've been recommending.  I've read about executables bypassing *hosts*, and so I thought I would pose this question.

Comment: If the answer to this is "no", a common alternative is to handle it at a network level, e.g. in a dedicated hardware firewall or the firewall tools built into some routers.